# Add Named Destination to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a named destination to an existing PDF using iTextSharp, but the [example code I've found online](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/named-destinations#1367-addnameddestinations.java) has not worked (the original example is in javascript). Am I doing something wrong? Below is the code I'm using, `New Text Document.pdf` is a single page PDF created from a `txt` file.

```
var sourcePdfPath = @"C:\Temp\New Text Document.pdf";
var destPdfPath   = @"C:\Temp\New Text Document_bettered.pdf";

using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
{
    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(destPdfPath, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        var destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
        var writer = stamper.Writer;

        writer.AddNamedDestination("Destination.Name", 1, destination);

        stamper.Close();
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are probably not using a recent version of iText.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie that sounds likely, thanks

Comment: Having the same problem, although I also tried iTextSharp 5.5.10. @tehDorf: Did you get your code to work?

Comment: @Chrisi no, I don't think so. I think I was able to solve my problem using a different approach. If I remember correctly, I was trying to make a link in a PDF that would open another PDF at a specific page, but I was able to do it by changing some of the attributes on a regular hyperlink.

Comment: I solved the problem with changing to iTextSharp 7. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956880/how-can-i-create-named-destinations-with-itextsharp