# How can I create named destinations with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to convert PDF bookmarks into named destinations with C# and iTextSharp 5 library. Unfortunately iTextSharp seems not to write named destinations into the target PDF file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.IO;

namespace PDFConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String InputPdf = @"test.pdf";
            String OutputPdf = "out.pdf";

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputPdf);           

            var fileStream = new FileStream(OutputPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

            var list = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream);


            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> entry in list)
            {
                object o;
                entry.TryGetValue("Title", out o);
                String title = o.ToString();
                entry.TryGetValue("Page", out o);
                String location = o.ToString();
                String[] aLoc = location.Split(' ');
                int page = int.Parse(aLoc[0]);

                PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, float.Parse(aLoc[2]), float.Parse(aLoc[3]), float.Parse(aLoc[4]));

                stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination(title, page, dest);
                // stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestinations(SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, false), reader.NumberOfPages);

            }
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

I already tried to use `PdfWriter` instead of `PdfStamper`, with the same result. I have definitely calls of `stamper.Writer.AddNamedDestination(title, page, dest);` but no sign of NamedDestinations in my target file.

Comment: I deleted part of your question because it would risk you to get a close flag (). You do know that iText(Sharp) comes with an AGPL license, *not* GPL or BSD?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution using iText 7 instead of 5. Unfortunately the syntax is completely different. In my code below I only consider the second level Bookmarks ("Outline") of my PDF.

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Navigation;
using System;


namespace PDFConvert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String InputPdf = @"test.pdf";
            String OutputPdf = "out.pdf";

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(InputPdf), new PdfWriter(OutputPdf));

            PdfOutline outlines = pdfDoc.GetOutlines(false);     
            // first level     
            foreach (var outline in outlines.GetAllChildren())
            {
                // second level
                foreach (var second in outline.GetAllChildren())
                {
                    String title = second.GetTitle();
                    PdfDestination dest = second.GetDestination();

                    pdfDoc.AddNamedDestination(title, dest.GetPdfObject());
                }
            }
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```